# List items get aligned to the item with border on the line above

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

I have a list of navigation tabs implemented using an unordered list and the active one will be highlighted with a border around it.

The issue with the tabs is that once an active item is set to take on a border:

`border: 1px solid #ff0000;`

the first item on the next line will be aligned after it.

This example will show you what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/stevenjs/JQawf/

If I remove the border, everything will be fine.

Can anyone help me please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm not sure if you have any restrictions here but you could add `border: 1px solid transparent` to all of your `li`'s and that will keep them a consistent size

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JQawf/2/)

Comment: thank you sooo much! I did what you suggested and it works like a charm!!! You helped me a lot!!!!

Comment: If you have some time, can you explain why my original list would get wrapped at the undesirable position? Simply because only one `li` has a border and the others don't? Just being curious here. Anyway, I can't say enough to thank you.

Comment: yeah when you dont specify fixed heights/padding/margin etc. an addition of pixels (in this case a border) can throw off the rest of them. So by keeping them all consistent but just hiding a border color on the ones not active you assure that they all follow the same properties.